# How do I create a dynamic alphabet id system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to create an alphabetic id system that extends beyond the 26 character limit.

I have already created an alphabetic id system by first generating a number, then converting it into a letter in the alphabet using this id as the index. But what I want to do, is after 26 characters have been used, I would like for it to continue with `AA`, `AB`, `AC` and so on.

```
var alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").split("");

var dataNo = object.find('.builder-list').attr("id").slice(2);
alphabet[dataNo]
```

The problem right now is that when the number hits 25 there is no letter to be translated to. What is desired, is that the letters start repeating again as in: `X`, `Y`, `Z`, `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, etc

Comment: in that case you need to track those ids which are already generated

Comment: *`is that when the number hits 25`* ... what *number*? `alphabet[dataNo]`? What? So, after `az` goes `ba`?... `.attr("id").slice(2)` 2 of what ID? To do what?

Comment: I have the slight feeling you don't need IDs at all...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ID are indeed required for all objects.

Comment: @brk why would I need that? If this was numbers I wouldn't need to track 1-27 just to type out a 28.

Comment: `mod` could be used to determine the rightmost letter. It looks like your replicating a base 26 system. Look into how base 8 or base 16 compare to base 10. Your string basically represents (letter1*26^2) + (letter2 * 26^1) + (letter3 *26^0). where each letter of three alphabet corresponds to a number value of 0..25 (0 being the 26th letter z, 1..25 are a..y).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a method to convert your number to your alphabet.  Similar to how hexadecimal works, as the number exceeds the alphabet range, your get the character for the division of the alphabet range, and add on the next alphabet character for the remainder.

```js
function convertNumberToId (number) {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toUpperCase().split('');
  
  if (number < alphabet.length) {
    return alphabet[number];
  } else {
    return (
      convertNumberToId(Math.floor(number / alphabet.length) - 1)
      +
      convertNumberToId(number % alphabet.length)
    );
  }
}

console.log(convertNumberToId(25));
console.log(convertNumberToId(26));
console.log(convertNumberToId(280));
```